# Enhanced Recurring Payments with Website Payments Standard Issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

Problem: Trying to pass along a variable Monthly Subscription cost to PayPal based on user-selected options on the form I created with more Values From Anothers Standart Products. Working Within Website Payments Standard with Enhanced Recurring Payment option.

Details: User visits "shop" page, Which Is a form with four line items, each line item Consisting of 2-7 options, each option with an associated price.

For example, line item 1 is "size of business" with the options being: a) 1-10 employees - $ 20 b) 11 - 20 employees - $ 30, c) 20+ employees - $40 he also bought an item with a fixed value $ 25, that is out a Recurring Payment.

Is this possible?

What is the correct way to solve this problem by api paypal? It is possible to attach a signature and a normal purchase in the same shipment?

What about Adaptative Payments to solve This Problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Website Payments Standard Recurring Payments lets you define trial periods; you could use such a trial period to include a higher one-off charge.

For details, please take a look at the [HTML variables page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU) for this product.

For example;
$50 / recurring
$100 / one-off

```
a1: 150 ($100 one-off plus $50 for the first month)  
p1: 1  
t1: M

a3: 50  
p3: 1  
t3: M
```

Whilst not perfect (technically the first charge is a trial period and not a one-off charge), Enhanced Recurring Payments is our only web-based recurring payments product offering guest subscriptions at this time, so Adaptive Payments would not be an option.